# Membership and fusions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Michael Potter in his "Set Theory and its Philosophy" separates two types of aggregations of objects:

- *Fusion* is a transitive aggregation: a part of an aggregated object becomes a part of the fusion;
- *Collection* is a non-transitive aggregation: a part of an aggregated object does not become a part of the collection (unless it is the object itself).

According to the same classification there are two corresponding types of parts:

- *Inclusion* is a transitive part: a part of an inclusion is a part of the whole;
- *Member* is a non-transitive part: a part of a member may not be a part of the whole.

From naive set theories we have an understanding on how inclusions are related to collections:
a subset is an inclusion of a set.

I am wondering how membership is related to fusions.

Following the definitions, we can associate a fusion with a collection of all parts of aggregated objects that became parts of the fusion.

Let's denote a fusion of objects in square brackets, similar to how we denote a set (collection).
If the aggregated objects are sets, we can write the following statements:

- if $A = \{a\}$ and $B = \{b\}$, then $[A,B] = \{a, b, \{\}, \{a\},\{b\}\}$;
- if $A = \{a, b\}$, then $[A] = \{a, b, \{\}, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

In those statements we assume $a$ and $b$ do not have parts.
But what if $A = \{\{a\}\}$, $a \ne \{a\} \ne \{\{a\}\} \ne a$?

Membership is not transitive, therefore $a$ is not a part of $A$.
From another hand, fusion is transitive.

Which statement is correct in this case:

- $[\{\{a\}\}] = \{\{a\},\{\},\{\{a\}\}\}$, or
- $[\{\{a\}\}] = \{a,\{a\},\{\},\{\{a\}\}\}$?

Comment: None of this is meaningful without more precise definitions.

Comment: @EricWofsey Are there more precise definitions?